# Passing data to modal codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently i have a table that is generated via DB and i want to view the details of the selected value on the data table. I separated the modal with view/users/modal. but there's an error
 **Message: Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object**
please help me to resolve this

I am running Codeigniter 3.1.10 
Xampp V3.2.3

**Data Table**

```
 <?php echo $this->load->view('users/Modal/view_modal'); ?>


  <tbody>
    <?php if(!empty($value)): ?>

       <?php foreach($value as $row): ?>   
         <tr>
           <td align="center"><?php echo $row->user_id; ?></td>
           <td align="center"><?php echo $row->firstname; ?></td>
           <td align="center"><?php echo $row->lastname; ?></td>
           <td align="center"><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
           <td align="center">

           <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#info_modal<?php echo $row->user_id; ?>">
           <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
          </button>

          <a href="<?php echo base_url('users/view_edit_form/'.$row->user_id); ?>" class="btn btn-success">
         <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
          </a> 

         <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">
         <i class="fas fa-ban"></i>
         </a>

         </td>


             <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**My Modal**

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="info_modal<?php echo $row->user_id; ?> " tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><?php echo $row->firstname; ?></h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                ...
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

I expect the output will display more information of the user but the actual output is an error message **Message: Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object**

Comment: Well, the problem is actually that `Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object`. Put a `{{ var_dump($row) }}` to see what `$row`contains

Answer (score 0):

try to check what `$row` contains.

If `->` don't work, try using `$row['user_id']`